# jMeter: load multiple rows from CSV file into HTTP body

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to build an HTTP request to a service which accepts a list of items, for example:

```
{
    "user": "john", 
    "table": "goods",
    "articles": [ 
        {"id": "003", "quantity": 1},
        {"id": "004", "quantity": 1},
        {"id": "023", "quantity": 2},
        {"id": "011", "quantity": 3},
        {"id": "063", "quantity": 1},
        {"id": "006", "quantity": 7}
    ]
}
```

My goal is to load **ALL the articles** from a CSV file, done as follows:

[image]

I would like to have something like:

```
{
    "user": "john", 
    "table": "goods",
    "articles": [ 
        {"id": "${id}", "quantity": ${qte}}
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help me?

---

---

UPDATE:

Dmitri T solved my problem, thank you!
I also asked him how to add a JSON object (a dictionary) to my body, while he answer I found a solution which I will share here in case someone needs it. If you want to add:

```
"user": {"id": 1, "name": "John"}
```

to your body content, you just need to do this:

```
def user = [:]

//populate user
user.put('id', 1)
user.put('name', 'John')

//add user entity to body content
content.put("user", user)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to have something like you provided above, the only way to dynamically build a JSON request body is constructing it programmatically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the request which body you want to parameterize
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def content = [:]
   content.put('user', 'john')
   content.put('table', 'goods')
   def articles = []
   new File('test.csv').readLines().each { line ->
       def article = [:]
       article.put('id', line.split(',')[0])
       article.put('quantity', line.split(',')[1])
       articles.add(article)
   }
   content.put('articles', articles)
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(content).toPrettyString(), '')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
3. That's it, when you run your test the PreProcessor will generate the request body from the CSV file and add it to the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler on the fly.

References:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, thank you for your answer. I think it is exactly what I'm searching for. Could you also telling me how to add directly a JSON entity to the script?

Instead that:
    "user": "john"

I would add:
    "user": {"id": 1, "name": "John"}